# Consequently subtract columns and get the resulted cumsum

Tags: python, pandas

Having the dataframe like this:

```
 |one|two|three|  
 | 1 | 2 |  4  |  
 | 4 | 6 |  3  |  
 | 2 | 4 |  9  |
```

How can I subtract values from column one from values of column two and so on and then get the sum of obtained values? Like

```
 |one|two|three|  one-two | one-three | two-three | SUM |
 | 1 | 2 |  4  |  -1      |   -3      |    -2     | -6  |
 | 4 | 6 |  3  |  
 | 2 | 4 |  9  |
```

As a result I need a df with only one-three columns and SUM onley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 2},
 'two': {0: 2, 1: 6, 2: 4},
 'three': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 9}})
```

### create column combination using `itertools.combinations`

```
## create column combinations
column_combinations = list(combinations(list(df.columns), 2))
```

### Subtract each combination column and create new column

```
column_names = []
for column_comb in column_combinations:
    name = f"{column_comb[0]}_{column_comb[1]}"
    df[name] = df[column_comb[0]] - df[column_comb[1]]
    column_names.append(name)

df["SUM"] = df[column_names].sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: @jas_0n, Please upvote my answer if you found useful.

Comment: Note that `df.sum(axis=1)` returns the sum of _all_ columns in `df`, not just the ones obtained by subtracting. Nice answer otherwise, I hadn't heard of this feature of `itertools`.

Comment: @Emerson Harkin thanks for pointing out. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]})
column_differences = df.apply(np.diff, axis=1)
total_column_differences = np.sum(column_differences.to_list(), axis=1)
df['SUM'] = total_column_differences
print(df)
```

Gives the following.

```py
   a  b  c  SUM
0  1  4  7    6
1  2  5  8    6
2  3  6  9    6
```

Answer (score 1):

DataFrames make operations like this very easy

```
df['new_column'] = df['colA'] - df['colB']
```

[PyData has a great resource to learn more.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion)

In your example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,4],[4,6,3], [2,4,9]], columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
df['one-two'] = df['one'] - df['two']
df['one-three'] = df['one'] - df['three']
df['two-three'] = df['two'] - df['three']
df['sum'] = df['one-two'] + df['one-three'] + df['two-three']
df.drop(columns=['one', 'two', 'three'], inplace=True)
```

```
# print(df)
   one-two  one-three  two-three  sum
0       -1         -3         -2   -6
1       -2          1          3    2
2       -2         -7         -5  -14
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only 3 columns and only want pairs of 2 features:

```py
from itertools import combinations
from pandas import DataFrame

# Creating the DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'one': [1,4,2], 'two': [2,6,4], 'three': [4,3,9]})

# Getting the possible feature combinations
combs = combinations(df.columns, 2)

# Calculating the totals for the column pairs
for comb in combs:
    df['-'.join(comb)] = df[comb[0]] - df[comb[1]]

# Adding the totals to the DataFrame
df['SUM'] = df[df.columns[3:]].sum(axis=1)
```

```
   one  two  three  one-two  one-three  two-three  SUM
0    1    2      4       -1         -3         -2   -6
1    4    6      3       -2          1          3    2
2    2    4      9       -2         -7         -5  -14
```